# Host FTP server on Github

Tags: github, github-pages, github-for-windows

Was wondering if there was a way of hosting a FTP server on github, and have it set up to use the FTP server from my Github page (username.github.io), like ftp://username.github.io

Can someone redirect me to an article or show me how to achieve this. Is there a repo I need to fork that does all this already?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't host an FTP server on GitHub. Aside from its webpage hosting functionality, GitHub is not a general hosting service.